# How to ignore all popups when loading a powerpoint file through applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, ms-office, powerpoint

I am loading a powerpoint presentation using applescript so I can automatically save it in another format.

Here is the code:

```
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    open "/Users/Me/Desktop/test.pptx"
end tell

set theOutputPath to "/Users/Me/Desktop/Export.pdf"
tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    save active presentation in theOutputPath as save as PDF
end tell


tell application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    close active presentation
end tell
```

This works, however when opening a certain document made with PowerPoint for Windows instead of opening, exporting, closing PowerPoint gives me a popup:

"This presentation contains ActiveX controls, which will not work in PowerPoint. If you save this presentation, the ActiveX controls will be removed"

Unless I press "ok" nothing happens. So I cannot fully script load/export/close as after load i have to click on Ok with the mouse.

What actually happens is: AppleScript executes the open, and immediately tries the save. However the application is blocked on the above popup so AppleScript gives the following error:

> Microsoft PowerPoint got an error: active presentation doesn’t
>   understand the save message.

So the script execution fails.

I searched in the dictionary and I don't find anything to solve this, nor did I find a solution in the PowerPoint preferences.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ok button is the default button, try:

```
activate application "Microsoft PowerPoint"
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Microsoft PowerPoint"
    keystroke return
end tell
end tell
```

Note : You must Enable Access for Assistive Devices

Comment: I tried this but the event happens to quickly. What it does is add a slide to the presentation. I think I need to add some kind of delay

Comment: I added a 30 second delay, that seems to do the trick. Thanks!